# Using an array to output results from a lookup criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I've tried searching the site, so sorry if this is a repeat. I'm not sure exactly how to phrase what I'm trying to do in excel.

Essentially what I have is a data sheet and a summary sheet. On the summary sheet I have several Countifs and Sumifs to give a general summary, heh.

What I want to create is an another tab to showcase the outliers from the data sheet, based on criteria in my countifs. I want to create an array to spit out results based on that lookup, say "agent name" for example, and then drag that down the sheet. That way, when the data sheet updates, the outliers will update as well.

=COUNTIFS(CallStats!AB:AB,"Y",CallStats!A:A,"Austin")
^ this is how I'm getting my count, so I'd want to find everything meeting that criteria and then spit out, say the lookup of column B.

I know I can simply use a pivot table to accomplish what I'm asking, but the data sheet gets replaced daily so the row count is always different and having to go in and constantly change the source data is a pain. Plus, with the way the pivot table shows hierarchy is messy, so I have been using lookups from the pivot, which are a nightmare as well. I'm open to alternative ideas, but I'd really like to get better with arrays. I simply don't have enough experience to confidently use them.

Any help is appreciated!